# AJAX append issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, append

i strugle with AJAX, i have difficulties to understand it...my issue is when i append only the data like this $('#blockAlarmeContent').append(data.TNT.RX); it returns the value but when i put the value in html structure and then append the html it doesn"t work..

what i want to do is to display the html structure in blockAlarmeContent (the content of the green header)
thank you !
here is my code :

```js
$('#boxLV1').click(function() {
  $('#mainViewContainer').animate({'left': '-30rem'}, 250, function(){

    // Appel AJAX pour récupération du contenu.
    $.ajax({
      url: 'Pages/index.php', //ou il y a le traitement json
      type:  'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: 'action=loadBlocSite',
      success:function(data){

                var alarmeContent = '';
                alarmeContent += '<div class="wrapContent">';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableHeader">';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCell_title">TNT</div>';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCell_title">FM</div>';
    alarmeContent += '</div>';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg">';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="table_row">';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_title">Criticité</div>';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_value">'+ data.TNT.Criticite +'</div>';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_value">'+ data.FM.Criticite +'</div>';
    alarmeContent += '</div>';// fin table-row
    alarmeContent += '<div class="table_row">';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_title">Sans supervision</div>';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_value">'+ data.TNT.Sanssupervision +'</div>';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_value">'+ data.FM.Sanssupervision +'</div>';
    alarmeContent += '</div>';// fin table-row
    alarmeContent += '<div class="table_row">';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_title">Non nominale</div>';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_value">'+ data.TNT.Nonominale +'</div>';
    alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCatg_value">'+ data.FM.Nonominale +'</div>';
    alarmeContent += '</div>';// fin table-row
    alarmeContent += '</div>'; //fin tableCatg
    alarmeContent += '</div>'; //fin wrapContent
  
    $('#blockAlarmeContent').append(alarmeContent);
        //alert(data.TNT.RX);
        //$('#blockAlarmeContent').append(data.TNT.RX);
        //callback(true);
      }
    });
  });
});
 
$('#boxLV2back').click(function() {
  $('#mainViewContainer').animate({'left': '0rem'}, 250, function(){
    //$('#blockAlarmeContent').empty();
  });
});
```

```css
.clsMainView{
 position: relative;

 height: 50rem;
 width: 30rem;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.clsMainViewContainer{
 position: absolute;
 height: 50rem;
 width: 90rem;
 /*background-color : red; */
}

.clsBoxLV{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin:1rem;
 padding:0;
 height: calc(100% - 2rem);
 width:28rem;
 background-color : red;
}

.clsBoxLVheader{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem;
 padding:0;
 height: 2rem;
 width: 100%;
 background-color : yellow;
}
.clsBoxLVtitle{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem;
 padding:0;
 height: 100%;
 line-height: 100%;
 width: calc(100% - 2rem);
}

.clsBoxLVback{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem;
 padding:0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 2rem;
}

.clsBoxLVContent{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem;
 padding:0;
 height: calc(100% - 2rem);
 width:100%;
}

.clsBlock{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem 0rem 0.5rem 0rem;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 background-color : green;
}
.clsBlockHeader{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem;
 padding:0;
 height:2rem;
 width:100%;
}
.clsBlockHeaderTitle{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem;
 padding:0;
 width:calc(100% - 2rem);
}
.clsBlockHeaderReduce{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem;
 padding:0;
 width:2rem;
}
.clsBlockContent{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0rem;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
}
.blockAlarmeContent{
 width: 100%;
 background: pink;
}
.tableHeader {
 position: relative;
 width: calc(40% - 1rem);
 display: block;
    float: right;
 width: 10rem;
 height: 2.5rem;
 border: 1px solid;
 background: bisque;
}
.tableCell_title {
 float: left;
 width: calc(50% - 0rem);
 height: 2.5rem;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.tableCatg_value {
 position: relative;
 width: calc(40% - 1rem);
 display: block;
    float: right;
 width: 10rem;
 height: 2.5rem;
 border: 1px solid;
 background: bisque;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
//-------------------------------- CREATION D'UN WEB SERVICE JSON --------------------------//

 //Création d'une action
 $currentAction = $_REQUEST['action'];
 
 
 switch($currentAction){
  case 'loadBlocSite': echo json_encode(loadBlocSite()); break;  
 }
 
 
 
 function loadBlocSite()
 {
  //Création d'un tableau
  $currentArrayData = array();
  
  //Remplir le tableau
  $currentArrayData['name'] = 'test';
  $currentArrayData['value'] = 'val';
  $currentArrayData['TNT'] = array(
        'Criticité'   => '10',
        'Sans supervision' => '8',
        'Non nominale'  => '5',
        '-3dB'    => '3',
        'RX'    => '4',
        'Perte HF'   => '15',
        'Décrochage HS'  => '6'
        );
        $dataContent['FM'] = array(
       'criticite'   => '2',
       'sanssupervision' => '6',
       'nonominale'  => '0',
       '-3dB'    => '4',
       'RX'    => '9',
       'Perte HF'   => '11',
       'Décrochage HS'  => '1'
  return $currentArrayData;  
 }
 
?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>

<!-- ################################ -->
<!--  CONTENU HTML DE CETTE PAGE -->
<!-- ################################ -->
<div id="mainView" name="mainView" class="clsMainView">
<div id="mainViewContainer" name="mainViewContainer" class="clsMainViewContainer">

<div id="boxLV1" name="boxLV1" class="clsBoxLV">

  <div id="blockAlarme" name="blockAlarme" class="clsBlock">
    <div id="blockAlarmeHeader" name="blockAlarmeHeader" class="clsBlockHeader">
      <div class="clsBlockHeaderTitle">Alarme</div>
      <div class="clsBlockHeaderReduce"><i class="fa fa-window-minimize" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blockAlarmeContent" name="blockAlarmeContent" class="clsBlockContent"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="blockTicket" name="blockTicket" class="clsBlock">
    <div id="blockTicketHeader" name="blockTicketHeader" class="clsBlockHeader">
      <div class="clsBlockHeaderTitle">Ticket</div>
      <div class="clsBlockHeaderReduce"><i class="fa fa-window-minimize" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blockTicketContent" name="blockTicketContent" class="clsBlockContent"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="blockSites" name="blockSites" class="clsBlock">
    <div id="blockSitesHeader" name="blockSitesHeader" class="clsBlockHeader">
      <div class="clsBlockHeaderTitle">Sites</div>
      <div class="clsBlockHeaderReduce"><i class="fa fa-window-minimize" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blockSitesContent" name="blockSitesContent" class="clsBlockContent"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="blockTech" name="blockTech" class="clsBlock">
    <div id="blockTechHeader" name="blockTechHeader" class="clsBlockHeader">
      <div class="clsBlockHeaderTitle">Technicien</div>
      <div class="clsBlockHeaderReduce"><i class="fa fa-window-minimize" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blockTechContent" name="blockTechContent" class="clsBlockContent"></div>
  </div>


</div>



<div id="boxLV2" name="boxLV2" class="clsBoxLV">
  <div id="boxLV2header" name="boxLV2header" class="clsBoxLVheader">
    <div id="boxLV2title" name="boxLV2title" class="clsBoxLVtitle">titre</div>
    <div id="boxLV2back" name="boxLV2back" class="clsBoxLVback"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div id="boxLV2Content" name="boxLV2Content" class="clsBoxLVContent">Content</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `alarmeContent = ` is right for the first line, but you should change to `alarmeContent += ` from the second line to the end, or else each line overwrites the precedent

Comment: i changed the =  with += in all lines except the first but still doesn"t work

Comment: your ajax request returns an empty response in your snippet, so we cannot really test it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are overwriting the variable!

```
alarmeContent = '<div class="wrapContent">';
alarmeContent = '<div class="tableHeader">';  //replaces last line
alarmeContent = '<div class="tableCell_title">TNT</div>';  //replaces last line
```

It should be +=

```
alarmeContent = '<div class="wrapContent">';
alarmeContent += '<div class="tableHeader">';
alarmeContent += '<div class="tableCell_title">TNT</div>';
```

Comment: thank's ..i edited the snippet with += but stil doesn"t work

Answer (score 2):

The variable alarmeContent is defined several times. You should concatenate your string like

```
alarmeContent +='...';
```

Also alarmeContent is a "standalone" variable and not part of the data-object.
So

```
$('#blockAlarmeContent').append(alarmeContent);
```

should do the job

Comment: i just edited all the mistakes that all of you mentionned but stil does not work

Comment: Then try to debug the values on the browsers console.
Add a `console.log(alarmeContent)` before appending it, to see if it contains the correct data.

Comment: And make sure your data-object contains all subobjects like TNT and FM. The console should help you here, too.

Comment: i it gives me this as error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'criticite' of undefined eventhough i have it in json array,..as it shown in the snippet (php part)

Comment: and also when i debug it in the browser console it gives me this Uncaught ReferenceError: alarmeContent is not defined

Comment: ok from your PHP you're not filling the FM value. So you can just use the TNT in javascript.

Comment: yes i'm filling it in my code and also add it in the snippet..all the information that i want to display are filled in the php file..but still does not work..can't figure it out

Comment: i tried to use only these $currentArrayData['name'] = 'test';
$currentArrayData['value'] = 'val'; and it works but with other arrays it does not .

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use object literals, so you have beautiful multiline strings:

```
alarmeContent = 
 `<div class="wrapContent">
     <div class="tableHeader">
     </div>
  </div> `
;
```